# call a method in Javascript file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

in a Struts 2 based application i have Java classes and JSPs. in the JSPs i have included Javascript files.
i have a Java method which return a string.
i want to call this method in the Javascript files.
how can I do this?

Comment: export Java Method as http-request and make request from js

Comment: Please use an upper case letter at the start of each sentence, for acronyms like JSP, and for any use of the word 'I'.  That post is painful to try and read.  Another tip: do not forget to add a question mark (?) to questions like "How I do this?"

Answer (score 2):

Struts is a server side framework, so your Java is running on your server.

JavaScript is usually found running in the browser (and it doesn't sound like you have involved any SSJS solution).

Therefore: You can't. The programs are running on different computers and can't interact directly.

You would need to issue a new HTTP request, including the data somewhere it can be retrieved (e.g. in a query string). You could do this by setting `location`, generating a `<form>` and calling its `submit()` method, using the `XMLHttpRequest` object, dynamically adding a `<script>` element with the `src` set appropriately and various other approaches.

Comment: i want to validate some text field (e.g text field can not be blank). and which text field i want to validate is coming from a string value in java method.

Comment: That doesn't change any of the limitations I just explained. You should probably try to figure out how to get that information to the browser with the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the Java/JSP string directly into the body of the page as a JS variable.  (If I understand you correctly, and I am not sure I do).

Comment: Yes, keep it simple. `<script>var jsvariable = '${javavariable}';</script>`.

Comment: i have used this code in js file:
var collegename= '${collegename}';
 alert("collegename"+collegename) 
regarding collegename having getter/setter in action class.
but it show colloge name is undefined,

Answer (score 0):

You mean either one of two things.

Either you want to call the method at render time, and include the output in your Javascript.  For that, call the method using JSP.

Or you want to call the method at 'runtime'.  If so, you need to do an ajax call from the browser, and call the method that way.  You could use different techniques for that (jax-rs comes to mind).  Maybe struts already has something; not sure about that.  Basically, you make an http request towards a servlet.  The servlet calls your method and returns the response.  Then your javascript handles the response.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following in your JSP?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <s:property value="JSMethodName"/>();
<script>
```

I mean the above will call a particular JS method once... you could even wrap that `<s:property>` tag in an iterator to call a number of methods... probably better to modify the above for after page load.

If the above is not sufficient you can use ajax methods to return a list of JS methods dynamically and invoke them... for that I would advise using the jquery and the S2 JSON plugin.